# Route not functioning as expected on React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a homepage assigned on package.json file "www.example.com/tracking"

I have the following routes:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/tracking">
      <Search />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/trackingdetails">
      <Map />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have a search page dedicated to the /tracking route and /trackingdetails is the details page of that searched tracking id. The domain I have matches the package.json homepage and when hosted it takes to the /tracking search page as expected and also when the search is done it works. But a direct link to example.com/trackingdetails doesn't work. How can I assign the routes a way so that it can recognize the direct path too?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a default root path `/`, you would need to also exact `/trackingdetails` so your routes look like

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/tracking">
      <Search />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/trackingdetails">
      <Map />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that ```example.com/tracking``` domain is hosted and ```example.com/trackingdetails``` isn't hosted so thats why it is giving 404 but I dont know the fix for this issue sadly